# Warning: indirect call without `*'

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, gnu-assembler, att

Having this simple assembly:

```
.text
    .globl main
str:
    .asciz "%i\n"
add:
    push %rbp
    mov %rsp, %rbp
    movl %esi, %eax
    addl %edi, %eax
    pop %rbp
    ret

main:
    mov $1, %esi
    mov $2, %edi
    lea add(%rip), %rax
    call %rax #what is wrong here? the rax should contain first instruction of add
    mov %eax, %esi
    xor %eax, %eax
    lea str(%rip), %rdi
    call printf
    xor %eax, %eax
    ret
```

I am getting error:

```
foo.s:17: Warning: indirect call without `*'
```

Why? The `%rax` should contain the address of function (as denoted in comment), and this is not `c`, where there are pointer with `*`, but register that contains an address. So what is wrong here?

Comment: AT&T syntax contains a lot of absurd rules, and one of them is requiring the `*` here. Just add the `*`, or switch to Intel syntax which is sane.

Comment: according to intel doc, the `call` instruction accepts an address. Which I am providing in the `rax` no matter if there is asterisk or not

Comment: The Intel doc doesn't describe AT&T syntax.

Comment: @interjay how would it look in nasm?

Comment: Simply `call rax`.

Comment: Some architectures and assemblers consider branching to data as dereferencing, and make you express that.  This assembler is saying we can't branch to a register itself, but we can branch to the address in a register and then execute the instruction at that address (which is the dereference).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change

```
call %rax
```

to

```
call *%rax
```

This is not the same as `call *(%rax)`. From @interjay's comment below:

> `call *%rax` calls the address stored in `rax` (which is what OP wants to do), while `call *(%rax)` calls the address stored in memory pointed to by `rax`

The asterisk indicates that the call is an indirect call. It means call function stored inside `%rax`

Comment: is it the same with a memory address? In case a function first instruction is not in `rax` but lets say in `0xdeadbeef`? Can I do `call *$deadbeef`?

Comment: yes, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9223756/what-does-an-asterisk-before-an-address-mean-in-x86-64-att-assembly and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56979796/what-does-callq-rax-mean

Comment: This is incorrect. `call *%rax` calls the address stored in `rax` (which is what OP wants to do), while `call *(%rax)` calls the address stored in memory pointed to by `rax`.

Comment: I actually tried myself with *%rax, but then added the parenthesis for style. I didn't know this made a difference. Thanks! I will fix the answer

Comment: This answer is likely wrong. _*_ on x86-64 has nothing to do with direct/indirect. It used to be the 32-bit x86, but it is **not** true for 64-bit.

Comment: Hmm, Maybe you are right. Can you give a reference where it says that is not true?

Answer (score 5):

AT&T syntax always requires a `*` on indirect calls, like `call *%rax`.  This sets RIP = RAX.
`call *(%rax, %rdi)` would load from memory like RIP = mem_load(RDI+RAX).
`call *foo(%rip)` would load a new RIP from memory at the address `foo`, using a RIP-relative addressing mode.

When it's missing a `*` but still unambiguously an indirect call (because of a register operand or a `(%reg)` addressing mode), the assembler will infer that and warn you about it.

---

**That AT&T syntax design avoids ambiguity** between `call foo` (direct) and `call *foo` (memory indirect with an absolute-direct addressing mode).

Normally in 64-bit mode you'd use `call *foo(%rip)`, but the ambiguity would still exist if `call foo` could mean memory indirect.  And of course the syntax was designed before AMD64 existed.

In Intel syntax, memory-indirect call that loads a pointer into EIP/RIP from memory at the address `foo` with absolute addressing would be:

- GAS Intel syntax: `call [foo]`, `call qword ptr foo`, or `call ds:foo`
- MASM: `call [foo]` might [ignore the brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25129743/confusing-brackets-in-masm32) so only `qword ptr` or `ds:` work.
- NASM: `call [foo]` or `call qword [foo]`

So as you can see, MASM-style Intel-syntax (as used by GAS `.intel_syntax noprefix`) uses `ds:` or `qword ptr` to indicate that something is a memory operand, allowing `call foo` to be a normal `E8 rel32` call direct.

Of course, as I said, in 64-bit mode you'd normally want to use `call [RIP + foo]` in GAS or `call [rel foo]` in NASM.  (In actual MASM, I think RIP-relative is on by default.)